# Cokriging Predict Function "Error in h(simpleError(msg, call))"

Tags: r, kriging, gstat, spatial-predicates

I tried to do CoKriging using gstat library in R. it works perfectly until the prediction function

```
CK <- predict(g, Grid)
```

It gave me this error:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'obj' in selecting a method for function 'coordinates': trying to get slot "bbox" from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object.

the grid

[image: example of my Grid]

g is both data sets

[image: The first data set]

[image: The second data sets]

Comment: Not sure we can help without knowing a bit more about what your `g` and `Grid` are. Clearly from the error something is wrong with them but we can't tell from here. Can you show where these things came from, and maybe do `summary` on them? Please edit the question and show us these outputs!